# Xamarin: platform dependent color resource

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, xamarin.forms

The following XAML creates an `OnPlatform<Color>` resource.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <OnPlatform 
        x:Key="SwitchOnColor"
        x:TypeArguments="Color"
                iOS="#4CD964"
                Android="#FA3F7E"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It's supposed to implicitly typecast to `Color` when needed, but in the C# code I have to write:

```
TextColor = (OnPlatform<Color>)Resources["SwitchOnColor"];
```

I get a typecast error if I write:

```
TextColor = (Color)Resources["SwitchOnColor"];
```

Is there a way to define a *real* platform-dependent color resource?

Comment: Why not apply it implicitly? It will save you code as well :) Also, I don't see why this shouldn't work. The type should still be `Color`.

Comment: Do you mean ‘Resources["SwitchOnColor"]‘?  Typecast error, cannot convert object to color.

Comment: What do you mean by "real platform-dependent"? OnPlatform<Color> is the real type of that object you are getting from resources

Comment: I mean real Color.  The Resource of type `Color`, not of type `OnPlatform<Color>`.  Otherwise the code becomes a bit unwieldy if I have other resources that do not have to be platform-dependent and can be defined as `<Color>...</Color>`.